# angular firebase realtime database update numeric index on item removal

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete specific index from my firebase data on click button.

So my initial firebase database is as bellow:

[image: Initial fb db]

After I remove the item in index 1 i have the following firebase db :

[image: After remove]

Today, this index make my application crash. I want, on my item removal, to update the index 2 to become 1 (in that case)

Here is my code for remove an item:

```
firebase.database().ref('/books/').orderByChild('id').equalTo(book.id).once("value", snapshot => {
        var promise = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
          promise.push(child.ref.remove());
        });
          Promise.all(promise)
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior: there is no way to remove a single item from an array in Firebase, without updating the entire array.

So you will have to:

1. Read the entire node into an array in JavaScript.
2. Remove the item you want from that array, which will then generate the correct new indexes for the remaining items.
3. Write the entire array back to the database again.

Comment: Perfect, I tried your method and it is perfect !! More precisions about the solved issue is that as Frank said i took an array with my entire node into it, then i requested my Firebase to get the index of the data i wanna delete. With this index, i splice my array to remove it locally. Then I just had to push my array to firebase, And magical is here !!!